# How can I get a "Defeat All Enemies" Fairy Chest when the enemies are behind a wall?

Tags: rogue-legacy

[image]

Sorry for the blurry thing (trait).

I tried to use the shout, but it didn't kill these enemies.

Comment: For this room specifically: crow storm or scythe.

Answer (score 22):

It's impossible to get over there and kill them, the only way to do this objective in this kind of rooms is to use spells that can pass through the walls.

**Spells that can go through walls**:

- Blade Wall
- Flame Barrier
- Chakram
- Axe
- Crow Storm
- Scythe

**Note that**:

- Blade Wall can only be used in rare cases of this rooms where enemies are very close to the wall
- Flame Barrier, Axe and Crow Storm are the only spells that can win this kind of objective in cases where enemies are below the ground.
- Chakram can clear most of this rooms, but will require some skill in certain cases. In most cases you will have to face yourself in the opposite direction then the enemy, throw and avoid the chakram so it would hit the enemy on its way back
- Crow Storm is obviously the easiest way to solve this kind of rooms, you don't even need to be able to see the enemies. It has 100% success chance in ALL variants of this rooms.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get over there physically. You need to use magic that goes through walls, such as the *Scythe* spell or Lich King's *Crow Storm* spell to kill those enemies.

Comment: Don't forget *Axe* and *chakram*.

Comment: Chris's answer seems to cover that, so I'll just leave this one be. I was answering for the specific screenshot, where I know you couldn't do it with chakram, and I suspect you couldn't do it with an axe.

Comment: Ah, his answer wasn't there when I commented